# How to pass color to the gauge chart based on array of values in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

How do I pass color to the gauge chart based on an array of values in d3.js?

This is the link I have referred to and I want to pass a different color to the arc based on the dynamic array value:

http://bl.ocks.org/msqr/3202712

Comment: Hi! Questions of Stackoverflow should be self-contained. Please edit your question and include your code (at least the relevant pieces).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the color is set in the `render` function

```
 .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
 })
```

If you want to use an array of colors, you should change this function :

```
var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'black'];

...
// in the render function
.attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors[i]
})
```

Comment: Hi Tim we tried the above answer and it worked . Actually i needed in such a way that the color from value 0-8.5 as one color , from 8.5-9.5 as one color and 9.5-10 as another color with padRad. please suggest regarding this . Thank you

Comment: This solution worked for me for changing the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above, it looks like you’re looking for d3’s [`scaleThreshold`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleThreshold) scale.

It maps a continuous domain to a discreet range. The length of the range has to be the length of the domain + 1. The domain is a series of thresholds, so you’d have

```
var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([8.5, 9.5])
    .range(["blue", "red", "orange"]);
```

So now `colorScale(0)` → `blue`, `colorScale(9)` → `red`, and `colorScale(9.7)` → `orange`.

Comment: Hi Noleli .I tried this method but it s not working as it is accepting the range which is defined with the help of minAngle and maxAngle. So it is taking the range based on arc and not the values. I also tried assigning colors as below   
      var color = ['pink','red']; 
And the below function in render()
       arcs.selectAll('path')
        .data(tickData)
        .enter().append('path')
        .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
          if(i<2.5){
          return color[i];}
          if(i>2.5){
          return color[i+1];}
        })